# How to use numpy to interpolate between pairs of values in a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have lists like these:

```
x_data = [3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 2]
y_data = [15, 20, 22, 23, 21, 14]
```

I'd like to interpolate between pairs of items in the list so that instead of have list of length 6, it's length n with equally space values between each pair of items within the list. My current approach is to use a list comprehension to go through pairs in the list and `np.extend` an empty list with the results. Is there a better, ready-made function to do this?

My current approach:

```
import numpy as np

x_data = [3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 2]
y_data = [15, 20, 22, 23, 21, 14]
result_x = []
result_y = []
[result_x.extend(np.linspace(first, second, 5)) for first, second, in  zip(x_data, x_data[1:])]
[result_y.extend(np.linspace(first, second, 5)) for first, second, in  zip(y_data, y_data[1:])]
print(result_x, '\n'*2, result_y)

Out: [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.0, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8.0, 8.0, 7.25, 6.5, 5.75, 5.0, 5.0, 4.25, 3.5, 2.75, 2.0] 



[15.0, 16.25, 17.5, 18.75, 20.0, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.0, 22.25, 22.5, 22.75, 23.0, 23.0, 22.5, 22.0, 21.5, 21.0, 21.0, 19.25, 17.5, 15.75, 14.0]
```

Comment: There are the functions in `scipy.interpolate` that would work. Or do you want something that is strictly numpy?

Comment: scipy is numpy under the hood

Comment: The posted code is incorrect. `y_data` is not used and `result` is used without being defined. Also the list comprehension is not assigned to any variable. Please post a working snippet so we can understand what exactly you need.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for the heads up, fixed it.

Comment: @busybear I'm open to approaches using any libraries

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are repeating elements when interpolating. (Out: [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, **5.0, 5.0,** 5.5, 6.0,) To avoid that you can do `np.linspace(first, second, 5)[:-1]`  which will discard the last interpolated element and therefore avoid duplicates. Note that you will have to handle the very last element by adding it manually.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Good spot, I think I'll run the generated lists through `np.unique` to remove the duplicate values and avoid need to manually add the last value.

Comment: No, don't do this. Imagine your ranges are not monotonic, so at some point you can have a decreasing range. You might then have repeated values at different places, doing `np.unique` will then remove some needed values and giving you a hard time debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function does what you want using [`np.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np

def interpolate_vector(data, factor):
    n = len(data)
    # X interpolation points. For factor=4, it is [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, ...]
    x = np.linspace(0, n - 1, (n - 1) * factor + 1)
    # Alternatively:
    # x = np.arange((n - 1) * factor + 1) / factor
    # X data points: [0, 1, 2, ...]
    xp = np.arange(n)
    # Interpolate
    return np.interp(x, xp, np.asarray(data))
```

Example:

```
x_data = [3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 2]
y_data = [15, 20, 22, 23, 21, 14]

print(interpolate_vector(x_data, 4))
# [3.   3.5  4.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5  7.   7.25 7.5  7.75 8.   7.25
#  6.5  5.75 5.   4.25 3.5  2.75 2.  ]
print(interpolate_vector(y_data, 4))
# [15.   16.25 17.5  18.75 20.   20.5  21.   21.5  22.   22.25 22.5  22.75
#  23.   22.5  22.   21.5  21.   19.25 17.5  15.75 14.  ]
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there is an interpolation function under numpy. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Scipy has an interpolation functions that will easily handle this type of approach. You just provide your current data and the new "x" values that the interpolated data will be based on.

```
from scipy import interpolate

x_data = [3, 5, 7, 8, 5, 2]
y_data = [15, 20, 22, 23, 21, 14]
t1 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x_data))
t2 = np.linspace(0, 1, len(y_data))

n = 50
t_new = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

f = interpolate.interp1d(t1, x_data)
x_new = f(t_new)

f = interpolate.interp1d(t2, y_data)
y_new = f(t_new)
```